# Prioritize focus on dialog box first based on tabindex="0" or JS method

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I know focus goes by order and can't change the order, but I am trying to prioritize focusing the dialog box from all the elements first. Also, the focus should be trapped on the button

I tried giving tabIndex="1" to dialog but it's getting out of focus.
I tried autofocus to the dialog box as well but still, it's not getting focused at first.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('para').focus();
});
```

```html
<div>
      <h1>lets priortize for focus during tab</h1>
    </div>
    <input tabindex="0" type="text" placeholder="tabindex0"/ >
    <input type="button"  tabindex="0">
    <button tabindex="0" type="button" >tabindex test</button>
    
    <div>
      
    <button tabindex="0"> priortize paragraph before me</button>
    </div>
    <dialog id="para" tabindex="0" open>
      <div><p >prior me </p></div>
      <button tabindex="-1">If I am not clicked don't focus  further</button>
    </dialog>
```

To trap focus I used tabIndex -1 but its not getting trapped
here is my js code as well. I tried to use focus method to focus the dialog box at first

Answer (score 0):

First, remove all `tabindex="0"` because it’s the default parameter and unnecessary.

To Focus an element before another, just add a Tab-Index higher than 0. For example

```
tabindex="1"
```

The element with the highest number will be focused first, then the element with the second highest and so on. After that all other Elements will selected from the top to the bottom.

You can find a full guide for TabIndex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex?retiredLocale=de).

**Here‘s an example:**

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('para').focus();
});
```

```html
<div>
      <h1>lets priortize for focus during tab</h1>
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="tabindex0"/ >
    <input type="button"  tabindex="0">
    <button type="button" >tabindex test</button>
    
    <div>
      
    <button> priortize paragraph before me</button>
    </div>
    <dialog id="para" tabindex="1" open>
      <div><p >prior me </p></div>
      <button tabindex="-1">If I am not clicked don't focus  further</button>
    </dialog>
```

Comment: its still not working, dialog with tabindex="1" is out of focus now. I tried that too but giving higher value , takes it out from getting focused.

All elements needs to get focused. But in different order

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove all your tabindex=0 from the inputs and buttons. It's already the default for these elements, so totally unncessary.

Secondly, also remove all tabindex=0 from your divs, spans and such, if they aren't really interactive.
Remove also the tabindex=0 from the dialog itself, as it isn't interactive either (only its children are interactive, not itself).
It's also normally useless to set them to tabindex=-1, as there is no reason to focus an element if it doesn't provide any interaction.

Simple text shouldn't be focusable. If you want to make sure that it is read by screen readers and other assistive tools, the solution isn't to focus it, neither automatically, nor manually, nor programmatively at any moment.
There are much better methods depending on the case: aria-live, aria-labelledby, aria-describedby.

More generally, never use a value other than 0 or -1 for tabindex. Using positive values allow to explicitly decide a fixed tab order, which looks very cool at first, but is in fact a nightmare to maintain at long term.
One day or another, you are almost sure to forget to update the fixed tab order when adding or reorganizing the elements on screen. It's a major problem for accessibility if the tab order isn't predictable.
Additionally, using positive tabindex values cause all elements without tabindex values to whether be put at the end of the tab order explicitly defined, or totally removed from tab order (even otherwise normally focusable elements).
IN short, a single error in your code and keyboard accessibility is completely lost. It's extremely dangerous.

Concerning focus in general, there are quite precise rules on how to do it right.
Normally, you must focus the first input field the user has to fill, the element the user is the most likely to interact with first, or the most probable option the user is likely to select.
If there is no clear "most likely", simply focusing the first input field is the best thing to do.

A final note: it's a good idea to use JavaScript to focus an element of the dialog when it appears. According to [caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com/), the autofocus attribute isn't supported everywhere. It's especially ignored on mobile devices.

Comment: I have tried JS way to focus first on the dialog. I have two dialog box, its not focusing on dialog box, its focusing all other elements and then focusing dialog boxes at last